# Database filter query Flask SQLAlchemy with query string

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm very new to python so I'm asking you for help.
I need to make query to a data base with a query string where number of key/value pairs might be from 1 to 4.
This is actually all I have for the moment.

```
class Sales(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    
    Transaction_date = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=False)
    Product = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)
    Price = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=False)
    Payment_type = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.Transaction_date}, {self.Product}, {self.Price}' 

@app.route('/sales/')
def query():
    
    args = request.args
    argsdict ={}
    for k, v in args.items():
        argsdict[k] = v
    query = Sales.query.filter_by.(argsdict) 
    return query
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried thus far? Your `def query()` hasn't made any attempt at producing a query. Showing what you've tried might also help clarify your question. As is stands I'd have to guess at what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I edited my attempt even though I realize my code doesn't make any sense. So what I'm trying to do is to pass values from query string to my database query.

Comment: What do the contents of `argsdict` look like?

Comment: dict with values like {Product=Product1}

Comment: and the query string will look like ?product=Product1&Payment_type=Visa$date=01022019

Comment: If the keys in your `argsdict` match the column names exactly, you just unpack them as keyword arguments. e.g. `query = Sales.query.filter_by(**argsdict)`.

Comment: Yes, it does work this way. Thank you a lot.